# How to disable shipping method from checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to remove the complete shipping method from the frontend.Even free shipping also we don't need.If we disable all the shipping methods from backend the next button will not come on the checkout page.Can anyone please suggest how to remove shipping method.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-remove-shipping-method-from-checkout-page-and-show-custom-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 remove shipping method from checkout page and show custom Message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-remove-shipping-method-from-checkout-page-and-show-custom-message)

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt overwrite this file in your custom module with rederer layou
methodvendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
<!-- ko if: (isConditionTrue) -->
<li id="custom_shipping_method" class="checkout-shipping-method" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading" role="presentation">
   <!-- Your code -->
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```