# How to skip Shipping method step in checkout if only one shipping method in Magento 2?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.8

I have only one shipping method on my website. Do I want to skip shipping method step on the checkout page?

Comment: You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their right solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As per Magento checkout flow, you must select the shipping method at checkout.

If you have only one shipping method then you can hide shipping section by CSS. **Don't use hard code for skipping shipping method**. This will effect checkout flow. **Just use CSS to hide shipping section** which does not effect any checkout flow of Magento.

```
.checkout-shipping-method .step-title {
    display: none;
}

.methods-shipping #checkout-shipping-method-load {
    display: none;
}
```

If you completely remove shipping method section and add shipping method programmatically. Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/175193/35758