# How to remove shipping method in checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, checkout-page

I want to remove shipping method from checkout page. Can you guide me how can I do?

[image]

Comment: what type of product you are using?

Comment: I am using Simple Product

Comment: you can use instead for simple use virtual product it will not show shipping

Comment: Please  check update question. 
I don't want to display shipping Methods

Comment: please follow this URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-how-to-remove-shipping-method-in-checkout-page