# How to remove shipping method in checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, checkout-page

How to remove shipping method from the checkout page?

But, If I am not select shipping method then I am not able to place the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not select shipping method then you are not able to place the order. Any way to achieve your task you need to follow this step:

[Magento 2 How to remove shipping method in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-how-to-remove-shipping-method-in-checkout-page/175193#175193)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific situation but if you don't want to show a shipping method to the customer, you might want to give "virtual products" a try. If your cart only contains virtual products, the shipping-method step is being bypassed in the checkout.

Comment: we will charge shipping when our order is deliver to customer because we have only purchase order payment method and I have only product type is simple

Answer (score 0):

You can remove certain shipping methods from the checkout page by simply disabling them in the configuration of your store.

Navigate **Admin Panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales >Shipping Methods**.

You will have a full list of your current shipping methods and you can enable/disable them to fit your needs.

In addition, you will not be able to place an order if a shipping method is not selected. To achieve that, try this: [Magento 2 How to remove shipping method in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-how-to-remove-shipping-method-in-checkout-page/175193#175193)