# Remove specific shipping method based on condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I have installed a **store pick up** extension in our website. This extension showing two option as radio buttons

Collect in Store

1. Yes
2. No

So if we select 'NO', then in shipping method,

There is an additional shipping method showing like below.

**Store pickup 0.00**

Can we hide this option from the list if the extension installed is enabled?

In which file we can hide specific shipping method based on condition.

Can anyone help me with the issue?

I need to hide the specific shipping method from the list of options.

Comment: check it's template file , it should be there

Comment: @magefms, No its not there in the template file, can we hide in an other way,using the condition

Comment: can you share link for that extension?

Comment: @magefms, here s the link https://www.wyomind.com/store-pickup-magento.html

Comment: @magefms, the shipping method begins with this word "pickupatstore_", can we hide this by using plugin or any other methods

Comment: do you want to hide option or hide the shipping methods itself?

Comment: @magefms, I need to hide only that option not entire shipping method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92900/discussion-between-magefms-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: @magefms, can you update me now

Comment: @magefms, did you check it?

Comment: yeah I check everything seems okay bro

Comment: @magefms,can you update me code pls

Comment: @magefms, can you help me on this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Comment: @magefms, one small issue i am facing, "my billing and shipping address same" checkbox getting hidden in checkout here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to resolve this error like below.

Added id for each tr that is, each shipping rates.

```
<tr class="row" data-bind="attr: {                                                    
                           'id': 'shippingval_' + method.method_code}
                            ,click: $parent.selectShippingMethod" >
```

Then using css, hidden the specific shipping method that is "pickupstore" in my case.

Hope this may help for others.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hiding with CSS is really not the right way. Technically, the shipping method is still selectable and you can run into a problem with this. You can use an observer or plugin to truly remove it based on your condition or at a minimum you can use a javascript mixin to remove it from the list before it reaches the html template.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, yes i tried that way, that will not hide the shipping method instead it will not render, if not render even pick up store also adding price, so i used above method

Answer (score 5):

In order to dynamically disable any given shipping method, we need to create 2 plugins. One will be in charge of shipping method validation( Enable or Disable ), Other one for filtering out disabled shipping methods.

Create these files in a custom module.

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
    <plugin name="bytepattern_customshipping_update_rate_result" type="Bytepattern\Customshipping\Plugin\ShippingMethod" sortOrder="500" />
    <plugin name="bytepattern_customshipping_update_disabled_or_enabled_rates" type="Bytepattern\Customshipping\Plugin\GetAllRates" sortOrder="600" />
</type></config>
```

> Plugin/ShippingMethod.php

```
<?php 
namespace Bytepattern\Customshipping\Plugin;

class ShippingMethod {

public $__code = array();

public function beforeAppend($subject, $result) { 
    if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) { 
        return [$result]; 
    } 

    $this->getShipCode($result);


    if ($this->isMethodRestricted($result)) { 
        try{
            $result->setIsDisabled(true);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 


    return [$result]; 
} 

public function getShipCode($shippingModel) {
    $this->__code[] = $shippingModel->getCarrier(); 
}

public function isMethodRestricted($shippingModel) { 
    $code = $shippingModel->getCarrier(); 

    // Here your desired logic should be implemented!
    // Here we are filtering out table rate for free shipping

    if(in_array('simpleshipping', $this->__code) && in_array('tablerate', $this->__code) && $code == 'tablerate') {
        return true; 
    }

    return false; 
} }
```

> Plugin/GetAllRates.php

```
<?php

namespace Bytepattern\Customshipping\Plugin;

class GetAllRates{

    /**
 * Disable the marked shipping rates.
 *
 * NOTE: If you can not see some of the shipping rates, start debugging from here. At first, check 'is_disabled'
 * param in the shipping rate object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $subject
 * @param array $result
 * @return array
 */

public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
{
    foreach ($result as $key => $rate) {
        if ($rate->getIsDisabled()) {
            unset($result[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}}
```

> Note: Replace Bytepattern/Customshipping with your Vendor/Module

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom module and create below files.

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
        <plugin name="restrict_shippingmethod" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ShippingMethod" sortOrder="500" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Plugin/ShippingMethod.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class ShippingMethod
{
    public function beforeAppend($subject, $result)
    {
        if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) {
            return [$result];
        }

        if ($this->isMethodRestricted($result)) {
            $result->setIsDisabled(true);
        }

        return [$result];
    }

    public function isMethodRestricted($shippingModel)
    {
        $code = $shippingModel->getCarrier();
        $restrictedMethod = ['replace_method_code'];

        if ($restrictedMethod && in_array($code, $restrictedMethod)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: hi @Yash, this code will just hide the method from list is it?

Comment: yes, it wont show this method when checkout.

Comment: But will it apply when pick up store is selected?

Comment: I am trying with ko binding like below, 
 <!--ko ifnot: method.method_code == pickupatstore_1 --> in methods.html file

Comment: No it wont apply as it will not show in frontend, so user will not be able to select it.

Comment: then, If customer select store pick up option, which shipping method gets apply?, that time it should be 0.00

Comment: Basically when someone choses store pickup then only that shipping method should be visible. But you want to hide it. So which method do u want to apply or what behaviour you are expecting it to be ?

Comment: If store pick selected, right now automatically, 0 price getting applied, if No selected, extra shipping method is showing as 0 in list, i just need to hide it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92988/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-yash-shah).

Comment: I am replacing replace method code with freeshipping_free shipping but it is showing  free shipping method on checkout page. @YashShah

Comment: Try to put log into the code and check if this code executes for your action or not. Also log name of shipping methods so that if you have some type mistake in shipping method name, you can solve that.