# How can I Remove Shipping Method in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.2

I want to remove Shipping method table, please check the screenshot below. Link to the  [Website](http://kiabzanew.site/test232)
When you are going through the checkout process, then you can see this option.

[image: Shipping Method]

Comment: you want to remove shipping method block or just that free method?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Shipping method from Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Shipping method.

Comment: I want to keep free shipping, just need to remove that table.

Answer (score 1):

you can find solution to remove shipping method block from given link
[Magento 2 How to remove shipping method in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-how-to-remove-shipping-method-in-checkout-page)

please accept if helpfull.

Comment: I tried this but getting stuck at some point. Is there any easy way to disable it or remove it or hide it ?

Comment: You can also ovveride checkout_index_index.xml and remove js component item for further understanding refere devdocs magento

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this

[Magento 2 How to remove shipping method in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/magento-2-how-to-remove-shipping-method-in-checkout-page)

for remove the shipping method from cart and checkout step.