# How to disable "Pay with Store Credit" option from checkout page Magento Commerce

Tags: magento2.3.3

In Magento 2.3.3 Commerce I want to use the Store credit for backend only.

**How to disable `Store Credit` option from the checkout page**?

[image]

Comment: Hi Adarsh,
did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No, I am hiding it from CSS atm. Let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: Yes I got solution for it. This block is managed by Knockout JS so I override JS and HTML files in my Theme and added a condition so this block is not appear on checkout page.

Comment: I was more interested in other solutions than overriding the files.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, Please check my answer for new approach. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you so it helps other developer looking for similar problem.

Comment: I have upvoted. I don't have time to test this solution at this stage. I will surely accept once I am able to test it and confirm it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Magento use LayoutProcessor to render components on checkout page.

You can remove any block on checkout page using LayoutProcessor in Magento.

I built a plugin to remove Store credit Option

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="remove_store_credit"
        type="Vendor\Module\Plugins\Checkout\GiftCardLayoutProcessor"
        sortOrder="1" 
        disabled="false"/>
</type>

    <?php

namespace Vendor\GiftCard\Plugins\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class GiftCardLayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $result)
    {
        // hide shipping address component
        unset(
            $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']
        );
        // hide store credit component
        unset(
            $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
                    ['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
                    ['beforeMethods']['children']['storeCredit']
        );
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Please follow this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

I tried example mentioned there but it was not working for me so I created a  plugin to customize layoutprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

After working on removing store credit in checkout and finding the above examples not working I dug into the problem and found at least on version 2.4.1 the solution is to use "afterMethods" instead of "beforeMethods".

I do not know which version changed this, but referencing the layout XML from the vendor directory we can see line: 22 references "afterMethods":

```
vendor/magento/module-customer-balance/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

To implement into your module do the following, create the file:

```
app\code\Vendor\YourModulePackageName\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

Paste this in as the contents of your modules checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="storeCredit" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this helps someone!